# Prevent more than one UIPopover from being displayed at a time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

My app has a monthly view and for each day in the month, on a long press, a popover is displayed.

I have used `self.view setExclusiveTouch:YES` to prevent more than one popover occurring at once but that still occasionally allows multiple popovers.

How can I prevent more than one UIPopover from being displayed at a time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all declare a property of type UIPopoverController (lets say activePopover).

In the method that is called on long press do this:

```
if (self.activePopover != nil)
{
    if (self.activePopover.popoverVisible)
        [ self.activePopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.activePopover = nil;
}
```

And then when you allocate the UIPopoverController on long press assign it to activePopover.
This way you always dismiss a visible popover and only then present a new one.

Comment: Thanks.  Was best way in the end.  I made some stupid mistakes which threw me of track

Answer (score 0):

You can disable any interactions outside popover by setting its `passthroughViews` property to empty array after its presentation.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that would have worked but I made some errors and got confused.  In the end this wasn't appropriate for the class structure I had

Answer (score 0):

What about a global boolean flag?

Create it as a property in a global class or in your viewcontroller and check it before opening any popup

Init it with `FALSE` value and when you are going to open a popup just check its value:

```
//In the method that handle the long press to open the popup
if(!self.popUpPresent)
{
    //open the pop up
    [self openNewPopUp];
    //put the flag
    self.popUpPresent = TRUE;
}
else
//There is a popup opened, do another stuff or nothing.
```

**Dont forget to reset it value again to `FALSE` every time you close a popUp.**

Hope it helps

Comment: Great idea.  I tried this but somehow I am still getting more than one popover displayed at once!!

Comment: Where/How do you store that flag? it seems that it is possibly losing its value or it is not setting to 'TRUE' correctly

Comment: I'm working on a solution.  Some of the other answers have good points but it somehow seems iOS recognises an additional touch BEFORE I can disallow a second popover.  I think it's a timing issue

Comment: try the "self.popUpPresent = TRUE;" inside of the 'init' method of your popUp...could help if it is a timing issue